# Guess the 9 letter word

Tags: riddle, word

Whole I am cut,
In parts I come in threes.
First I am scarlet,
Second I am first,
Third I am an age,
Fourth I tell tales,
Fifth I have eaten,
Sixth I scatter.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Lacerated

Whole I am cut,

> The definition of lacerate is *to make deep cuts in*.

In parts I come in threes.

> The rest of the clues correspond to three letter words.

First I am scarlet,

> **lac** is a resinous substance secreted as a protective covering by the lac insect usually red in colour.

Second I am first,

> **ace** is often used to represent one in cards (also can be both high and low card).

Third I am an age,

> **era** is a long an distinct period of time, an age.

Fourth I tell tales,

> **rat** can be sland for a person who is deceitful or disloyal by telling tales.

Fifth I have eaten,

> **ate** is the past tense of eat.

Sixth I scatter.

> **ted** means to turn and spread out.

Comment: that was quick!

Comment: Thank you, for me the key clues here were the 'fifth' and the 'Whole I am cut'. There weren't many other words I could think of to fit these and the rest of the puzzle slotted into place after that.